# How to connect and access Mapd Database by GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotools, boundless-suite, mapd

In my project requirement to access table data from Mapd Database on GeoServer

Mapd(GPU Based database) Database documentation link:
https://www.mapd.com/docs/latest/mapd-core-guide/users-and-databases/

But in GeoServer provided some extension to connect and access particular database

GeoServer Extension link:

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/index.html#data-database

How can I connect MapD databse with geoserver is there any plugin.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no current support for this database. Looking at the documentation it seems to support JDBC so it would not be that hard to write a JDBC based datastore for it.

To do that you should probably work through the [simple CSVDataStore tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html) and then look at how the [other JDBC stores](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/plugin/jdbc) are written.

Alternatively you could look to one of the [commercial support organisations](http://geoserver.org/support/) to do the work for you.

*Disclosure I work for one of those organisations.*